# Auto generating a timestamp using $setOnInsert during upsert

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

We have been using the following command in MongoDB 2.4.* to create a field with auto-generated time-stamp values in inserted documents while not touching the same field for updates:

```
db.entity.update({EntityId : "ID01"}, 
                 {$setOnInsert : {Created : Timestamp(0,0)}, $set : {Name: "Abc"}}, 
                 {upsert : true})
```

This did work fine in 2.4.* with the inserted document having the field populated with the current time-stamp value:

```
{
   "_id" : ObjectId("54e312dc649bb37cf4ab413a"),
   "Created" : Timestamp(1424167644, 1),
   "Name" : "Abc",
   "EntityId" : "ID01"
}
```

However, when we run the same command in MongoDB 2.6.7, we end up with an empty time stamp:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("54e312e712e476107488a632"),
    "EntityId" : "ID01",
    "Created" : Timestamp(0, 0),
    "Name" : "Abc"
}
```

Is there a way to reproduce 2.4 behavior in 2.6?

Comment: I don't understand - it looks like MongoDB executed the update as you wrote it. What exactly was different between 2.4 and 2.6? Why are you using Timestamp, which is meant as a MongoDB internal type, rather than a Date type?

Comment: We use Timestamp to have server generated unique timestamps and utilise them for queries based on a snapshot in time. The difference we are seeing between 2.4 and 2.6 is that we end up with `{"Created" : Timestamp(1424167644, 1)}` when we run the update in 2.4 and `{"Created" : Timestamp(0, 0)}` when we run it in 2.6.

Comment: There's a new operator [`$currentDate`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/currentDate/) that's meant to replace using `Timestamp()` for auto-populating timestamps server-side, but I can't get it to work with `$setOnInsert`. If you can't get it to work either, I would file a ticket in the [MongoDB SERVER project](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER) explaining your use case and see what they say.